# reformat json with jq - collect results in array

Tags: json, group-by, jq

I have a query that returns json like this:

```
{
  "hostname": "seapr1pgdb032",
  "ip": "10.215.0.6",
  "dataCenter": "seapr1"
}
{
  "hostname": "seapr1cpndb001",
  "ip": "10.203.0.41",
  "dataCenter": "seapr1"
}
{
  "hostname": "seapr1dhcp01",
  "ip": "10.205.3.212",
  "dataCenter": "seapr1"
}
```

The dataCenter can vary, I would like to collect all the hosts for each dataCenter into a single object like this:

```
{
 "dataCenter": "seapr1",
 "hosts": [
    "seapr1pgdb032",
    "seapr1cpndb001",
    "seapr1dhcp01"
  ] 
}
```

Working from [Reshaping JSON with jq](https://programminghistorian.org/en/lessons/json-and-jq) I thought this would do it:

```
{dataCenter: .dataCenter, hosts: [.hostname] }
```

but I get three dataCenter objects, not the single consolidated one I expected:

```
{
  "dataCenter": "seapr1",
  "hosts": [
    "seapr1pgdb032"
  ]
}
{
  "dataCenter": "seapr1",
  "hosts": [
    "seapr1cpndb001"
  ]
}
{
  "dataCenter": "seapr1",
  "hosts": [
    "seapr1dhcp01"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Easy. Start with `jq -s 'groub_by(.dataCenter)'`, you can do it on your own.

Comment: Thanks  - I think I could have used this too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a jq solution that avoids the built-in `group_by` filter for the reasons explained in the comments below.

```
# This stream-oriented variant of the built-in `group_by` emits a stream of arrays,
# each array representing a group. The main advantages over `group_by` are
# that no sorting is required, and the ordering of items within a group is preserved.
# There are no restrictions on f or the items in the stream;
# in particular, f may evaluate to any number of values,
# but if f evaluates to empty at any item in the stream, then that item will in effect be discarded.
# Example:
#  GROUPS_BY( 4,3,2,1; . % 2 ) => [4,2] [3,1]

def GROUPS_BY(stream; f): 
  reduce stream as $x ({};
    reduce [$x|f][] as $s (.;
        ($s|type) as $t
        | (if $t == "string" then $s
           else ($s|tojson) end) as $y
        | .[$t][$y] += [$x] ) ) 
  | .[][] ;
```

Using the -n command-line option, we can avoid "slurping" the input by writing the solution as follows:

```
GROUPS_BY(inputs; .dataCenter)
| {dataCenter: .[0].dataCenter, hosts: map(.hostname) }
```

Comment: https://jqplay.org/s/risDCfxm5j <= i dont want the loop to create another object i want to modify the orginal with each iteration can you help ?

Comment: @joseph - Please ask a new SO question in accordance with the [mcve] guidelines.

Comment: thank you for taking the time to answer me , you'll find everything in here if you are willing to help https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/5275389/Append-key-to-json-object-with-jq

Comment: Answered there.  It would probably be a good idea if you followed the [mcve] guidelines ton codeproject.com as well, i.e. showed both the output you actually want, as well as your attempt using jq.

Comment: omg thank you for your kindness, the thing is i spent like 2 days on it and i was getting desperate and the jq official docs let's say could be better. Thank you sir

Comment: Thank you - just want I needed.